# Macro VBA find specific column

Tags: excel, vba

I would need to find a specific word on row 3 such as Budget and Status after that, I would need to delete the entire column which contains Status and Budget.

PS. can be more words and how to make it go to the last column and find those specific words

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for single words and delete columns quickly and simply with 1 line of code:

```
Cells.Find(What:="Budget", After:=Range("A3"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).EntireColumn.Delete
```

This line finds **What** you want starting from cell **A3** and searches the **SearchOrder** is by row.

If you ever want to find more words, just copy and paste the code and change the **What**

Comment: I get a message box that invalid outside procedure. It highlights "Budget"

Comment: Sorry I had `.copy` instead of `.delete` try again it will work. I've pre-tested

Answer (score 0):

This simple code will loop through row3 backwards and if it finds the values you are looking for it will delete the column (Note: you have to loop backwards from the last column). You can add more words by copying `Or .Cells(3, i).Value = "Budget"` and pasting it in front of `Next`, then change the word "Budget" as needed.

```
Dim lCol As Long, i As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = lCol To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(3, i).Value = "Status" Or .Cells(3, i).Value = "Budget" Then
            .Cells(3, i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End With
```